# Getting error when I try to connect Firestore test app via React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have setup the firestore configuration in a seperate file called "firestore.js" and it looks like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Then I import this file in my component.jsx and look like this:

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./config/firebase";

export default function MyAlerts() {
  const querySnapshot = getDocs(collection(db, "myAlerts"));
}
```

It throws me an error in the import db:

**Could not find a declaration file for module './config/firestore'. '/src/config/firestore.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7016)**

Even if I try to run then I get this file on the browser console:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at firestore.js?t=1697815860116:5:11**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is complaining about the lack of a declaration file for your JavaScript module. This can be resolved by adding a firestore.d.ts file in the same directory as your firestore.js and writing the following declaration:

```
declare module './config/firestore';
```

And for the other error you may need to use a tool like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to load the environment variables in your firebaseConfig.

Also ensure that your environment variables are correctly defined in a .env file in the root of your project directory.

Comment: Its "process.env" was causing the error and if I put the codes directly it works fine, but not using with environment variables. React should load custom variables from .env automatically and available through the app. Why its not working or causing this errro? do I have to do anything else than mentioning in the .env file?

Comment: Have you installed the dotenv package in your project?